# Power Matrix Row showing repeating values

Tags: powerbi, dax

[I have 2 Column Act 603000(Detailed) and Budget 603000 and I need to replace the repeating values to be either Blank or zero. I tried using (if ("hasonevalue") but hasn't worked.
my formula for Budget 603000 is
Budget 603000 =

Calculate([Budget],treatas(Values('Project lookup Final'[Site & Project ID]),'BUdgets Exc REfurbs'[Site & project ID]))
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdWtF.png)

Sample Data

| Site_cc | AX Project Code for Invoicing | Site/Project/Description | Actuals | Full Budget F23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Museum | T4059 | Total | 2775 | 25000 |
| Museum | T4059 | T4059-C/note for Ubiquiti UniFi | (126) | 25000 |
| Museum | T4059 | T4059-Install CCTV at Museum Torando | 1581 | 25000 |

Comment: Please post some sample data. You are giving us nothing to go on.

Comment: Apologies..have upodated sample now..I need to remove the repeating totals in the Full Budget F23 Column. For example T4059-C/note for Ubiquiti UniFi should be zero in the Full budget F23 Column

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you want to mark the duplicate value in a table. I have taken a simple example of table having columns A1, A2.

Use the below calculated table to create the same:

```
SlicerTable = DATATABLE("a1",STRING,"a2",INTEGER,{{"A1",1200}, {"A2",2000}, {"A3",2000}, {"A4",3000}})
```

Now first create a serial number based on your unique column. In the above table unique column is **A1** This column should be sorted first to get correct values. Below is the measure :

```
Sno = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(SlicerTable),filter(all(SlicerTable),SlicerTable[a1]<=max(SlicerTable[a1])))

sum = SUM(SlicerTable[a2])
```

Now subtract Sno with rankx function to mark duplicate values with 1. Below is the measure and screenshot

```
Calculated A2 = 
var Duplicate  = [Sno]- rankx(all('slicerTable'[a1],'slicerTable'[a2]),[sum],,ASC)
Return
if(Duplicate = 0,sum(SlicerTable[a2]),0)
```

[image]

Please accept the answer if you find this solution effective.

Comment: Thanks..for the calculation..However I dont need to mark the Duplicate values, I need to show them as zero or blank using Dax.  For example T4059-C/note for Ubiquiti UniFi should be zero in the Full budget F23 Column

Comment: I have updated my answer. It's simple , once you have marked duplicate value with1 just put a if statement to replace 1 with 0 and 0 with [Full budget F23 Column]